# Issue with 'npx create-react-app' command not working

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

I've been trying to use the 'npx create-react-app' command to create a new React application, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Has anyone else experienced this issue recently?

I have a stable internet connection and have made sure that Node.js is up to date on my system. However, whenever I run the 'npx create-react-app' command, it fails to initiate the React application creation process. I've received an error message, but it doesn't provide much information about the problem.

I've tried multiple times and even searched for similar issues online, but I couldn't find any recent reports or solutions related to this specific problem. My global npm packages, including 'create-react-app,' are also up to date.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my local setup or if there might be an issue with the 'npx create-react-app' command itself. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has any insights on how to resolve this, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Log:

```bash
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at
```

Comment: Most likely an Internet issue.

Comment: I suggest you trying with a different internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Reactjs new docs said that you should use vitejs or nextjs/remix command line for reactjs.
Reference: [Docs](https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project)

Your `nxp create-react-app` take too much time to install all the dependency so use this:

Try this command to create a react app

`npx create-vite-app@latest`